# how can i copy all the xml files which is having current date as filename from all directories

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I want to copy all the xml files which is having current date as file name from all directories. Below is the script i have written.

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT_DATE=`date +'%d%m%Y'`
Temp_Path=/appinfprd/bi/infogix/IA83/InfogixClient/Scripts/IRP/New_Vendors/
FILE_PATH=/bishare/DLSFTP/DLSTREAM/
FILE_DATE=`date -d "-2 days" +"%Y%m%d"`
cd $FILE_PATH
find . -name '*$FILE_DATE*.xml' -exec cp $Temp_Path
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your `find` statement is wrong. You should end it with `\;` to indicate the end of the `exec` command and put `{}` where the name of your file found should come in the command. So, you want :

```
find . -name "*$FILE_DATE*.xml" -exec cp "{}" "$Temp_Path" \;
```

---

**Edit**

As stated in the comments, there were also a problem in your initial post with your single quotes that should be double quotes. You might be interested by [this man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html). In particular by these sections :

> **-exec *command* ;**
>
> Execute *command*; true if 0 status is returned. All following arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until an argument consisting of `;` is encountered.  The string `{}` is replaced by the current file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it is alone, as in some versions of find. Both of these constructions might need to be escaped (with a `\`) or quoted to protect them from expansion by the shell.  See the EXAMPLES section for examples of the use of the `-exec` option. The specified command is run once for each matched file. The command is executed in the starting directory. There are unavoidable security problems surrounding use of the `-exec action;` you should use the `-execdir` option instead.
>
> **-exec *command* {} +**
>
> This variant of the `-exec` action runs the specified command on the selected files, but the command line is built by appending each selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of the command will be much less than the number of matched files.  The command line is built in much the same way that `xargs` builds its command lines.  Only one instance of `{}` is allowed within the command, and (when find is being invoked from a shell) it should be quoted (for example, `'{}'`) to protect it from interpretation by shells. The command is executed in the starting directory. If any invocation returns a non-zero value as exit status, then find returns a non-zero exit status. If find encounters an error, this can sometimes cause an immediate exit, so some pending commands may not be run at all. This variant of `-exec` always returns true.

Comment: single-quotes does not expand `bash` variables (or) preserve white-spaces, need to double-quote it.

Comment: I think this should work too: `find . -name "*$FILE_DATE*.xml" -exec cp -t "$Temp_Path" {} +`